# How to mock static method in Java?

Tags: java, junit, tdd, mockito, powermock

I have a class `FileGenerator`, and I'm writing a test for the `generateFile()` method that should do the following:

1) it should call the static method `getBlockImpl(FileTypeEnum)` on `BlockAbstractFactory`

2) it should populate variable `blockList` from the subclass method `getBlocks()`

3) it should call a static method `createFile` from a final helper class `FileHelper` passing a String parameter

4) it should call the run method of each `BlockController` in the blockList

So far, I have this empty method:

```
public class FileGenerator {
    // private fields with Getters and Setters

    public void generateBlocks() {
    }
}
```

I am using JUnit, Mockito to mock objects and I've tried using PowerMockito to mock static and final classes (which Mockito doesn't do).

My problem is: my first test (calling method `getBlockList()` from `BlockAbstractFactory`) is passing, even though there is no implementation in `generateBlocks()`. I have implemented the static method in `BlockAbstractFactory` (returning null, so far), to avoid Eclipse syntax errors.

How can I test if the static method is called within `fileGerator.generateBlocks()`?

Here's my Test Class, so far:

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
public class testFileGenerator {
    FileGenerator fileGenerator = new FileGenerator();

    @Test
    public void shouldCallGetBlockList() {
            fileGenerator.setFileType(FileTypeEnum.SPED_FISCAL);

            fileGenerator.generateBlocks();

            PowerMockito.mockStatic(BlockAbstractFactory.class);
            PowerMockito.verifyStatic();
            BlockAbstractFactory.getBlockImpl(fileGenerator.getFileType());
    }
}
```

Comment: abstract methods cannot be static

Comment: The simplest answer is if you've decided to do TDD, kick the habit of writing static methods :)

Comment: @ArtB it's a static method from an Abstract class, not an abstract static method. EDIT: just saw the error in my question. Fixed.

Comment: @Affe well, if there really isn't any other way, I'll change it...

Comment: Not an answer to your question, just a tip: instantiate your `FileGenerator fileGenerator = new FileGenerator();` in your test method or in your @Before, not as a member of your test class. With your current implementation you will share the instantiated `fileGenerator` over the tests in your test class (assuming that you also want independent tests)

Comment: @user1042273 can you post the static method in `BlockAbstractFactory` you want to have mocked?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have no experience with PowerMock, but since you didn't get an answer yet I'm just been reading through the documentation to see if I can help you a bit on your way.

I found that you need to prepare PowerMock so that I knows which static methods it needs to prepare to be mocked. Like so:

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(BlockAbstractFactory.class) // <<=== Like that
public class testFileGenerator {
    // rest of you class
}
```

[Here](http://code.google.com/p/powermock/wiki/MockitoUsage) you can find more information.

Does that help?

Comment: Thanks!! It worked when I added @PrepareForTest and when my test class extended TestCase!

Here's the full solution:

`@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(BlockAbstractFactory.class)
public class testFileGenerator extends TestCase {
  // same code, with your @Before and @After suggestion
}`

Comment: @user1042273 Hey nice one! Remind the comment of Affe though. Static methods are a pain with TDD. Use them with care. If you're adding state to static classes / public static methods, you'll have a hard time TDD them. You'll get there, and thank you for the question, I never heard of a mocking framework that can handle static classes :). I'll upvote it. Cheers and have fun!

Comment: Another issue to consider is that mocking static methods requires bytecode manipulation at runtime and comes at a performance cost. If you're only mocking one or two static methods you may be alright, but if you do it often you can really slow down your tests.

Comment: @bcarlso Doesn't the creation of new subclasses through CGLIB, which every other mocking tool does, *also* require bytecode manipulation at runtime? I don't really see much of a difference...

Comment: @Rogerio Maybe it does as well. I have experienced a significant difference in performance when mocking standard vs static methods. I don't know the details, so it may not be the bytecode manipulation. Thanks for straightening me out. I'll have to look into the differences a bit more.

Answer (score 1):

Working example:

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({ClassStaticA.class, ClassStaticB.class})
public class ClassStaticMethodsTest {

    @Test
    public void testMockStaticMethod() {
        PowerMock.mockStatic(ClassStaticA.class);
        EasyMock.expect(ClassStaticA.getMessageStaticMethod()).andReturn("mocked message");
        PowerMock.replay(ClassStaticA.class);
        assertEquals("mocked message", ClassStaticA.getMessageStaticMethod());
    }
```