# Mockito: error mocking persistence?

Tags: java, unit-testing, nullpointerexception, mockito, persistence

I am getting a null pointer exception at the following line when trying to set up Junit Tests:

```
private final EntityManagerFactory factory;

    public EntityManagerProvider( Config config, String persistenceUnit) {
        this.factory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(persistenceUnit,
                                                              config.getDbProperties());
    }
```

Is there a way that I can mock the return value of `Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory` ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TDD: how to mock static method in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15439592/tdd-how-to-mock-static-method-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

You can use  [PowerMockito](https://github.com/jayway/powermock/wiki/MockitoUsage),to mock the static method,

Answer (score 0):

The method you are trying to mock is defined as static.
public static EntityManagerFactory createEntityManagerFactory(String persistenceUnitName, Map properties) {}

It has to be explicitly mentioned in the test class. @PrepareForTest(Persistence.class)

For more information, as talex pointed it's the same issue which was already solved.
[TDD: how to mock static method in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15439592/tdd-how-to-mock-static-method-in-java)