# Inject a value to a variable in integration test

Tags: java, spring, integration-testing, powermock

I am trying to test this method in a class called `AbcDAO`:

```
public List<AbcVO> getCost(List<AbcVO> items) throws ParseException {
    try {
        String var;
        final Map<Object, Object> params = new HashMap<Object, Object>();
        for (final AbcVO abcVO : items) {
            if (Xyz.isTime(abcVO.getDate())
            {
                if (AppConstant.IT1.equalsIgnoreCase(abcVO.getItemFlag())
                    || AppConstant.IT2.equalsIgnoreCase(abcVO.getItemFlag())) {
                    var = "IT_New";
                } else {
                    var = "IT_Old";
                }
                final List<Map<String, Object>> result = this.runQuery(var);
                {Code to populate abcVO's cost field with amt}
            }
        }
        return items;
    } catch (final ParseException e) {
        throw new Exception("AbcDAO", "getCost", e, AppConstant.ERR_STRING);
    }
}
```

As we see there is a static call to `abcVO.getDate` and its in the `XyzDAO` class and looks like:

```
public static boolean getDate(Timestamp ts) throws ParseException {
        final java.util.Date date = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy").parse(AppConfig.ProcDate);
        final Timestamp ts = new Timestamp(date.getTime());
        if (ts.compareTo(ts) < 0)
        {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
}
```

What I want to test is simple - I want to verify that if I set the `itemFlag` to `AppConstant.IT2`, the var should equal `IT_new`  and verify the return amount. 
    Here is my test class:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "classpath:test-context.xml" })
public class AbcDAOTest {

    @Autowired
    private AbcDAO abcDAO;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
    }

    @Test
    public final void testGetCost() throws MIBException {
        // Create the item list
        final AbcVO abcVO = new AbcVO();
        abcVO.setItemFlag(AppConstant.IT2);
        final List<AbcVO> items = new ArrayList<AbcVO>();
        items.add(abcVO);

        this.abcDAO.getCost(items);
        final String expectedCost = "1237";
        assertEquals(items.get(0).getCost(), expectedCost));
    }
}
```

The problem I'm running into is I'm getting a `NPE` on `.parse(AppConfig.ProcDate)` on the static call as the `ProcDate` is null.
    My question is can I inject that value into this test (e.g. `AppConfig.ProcDate = "12/01/16"`) ? Also how can I verify the value of var which is a private variable?
    Else, is there some other way to test this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15439592/tdd-how-to-mock-static-method-in-java

Comment: That brings me to the question - does mocking and integration test go together?

Comment: I am trying to use Powermock by inserting these 2 lines:
@PrepareForTest(XyzDAO.class) on the class and   MemberModifier.stub(MemberMatcher.method(XyzDAO.class, "getDate")).toReturn(true);
However, it still calls the method, gets inside it and throws the NPE.

Comment: Try modelling your spec after the working example at the bottom of the page. Also, please edit your post so the actual content of the spec is available for review.

Comment: Testing code with nested static helpers is always a pain, try to refactor to dependency injection http://aburmeis.tumblr.com/post/153810978416/refactor-towards-test-static-helpers

Comment: @ArneBurmeister Can't agree more but unfortunately that code cannot be changed (for some irrelevant reason whatsoever) ... all I am looking for are
1. capture the var value
2. inject a value into AppConfig.ProcDate